# Tcl appears to be in the wrong location in my Python27 directory. How can I change this?

Tags: python, powershell, tcl

I'm following the Data Visualization tutorial on Newcoder.io using Powershell on Windows 10, and have come into trouble running a python script that should return a .png file. It appears it can't find the Tcl file

```
c:/python27/lib/tcl8.5
```

It's actual location is

```
C:\Python27\tcl\tcl8.5
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Below is a transcript of the error message I got when trying to run the program.

```
(datavizproj)PS C:\Users\Director UYE\Projects\new-coder\dataviz\MySourceFiles> python graph.p
y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graph.py", line 89, in <module>
    main()
  File "graph.py", line 84, in main
    visualize_days()
  File "graph.py", line 67, in visualize_days
    plt.plot(data_list)
  File "C:\Users\Director UYE\.virtualenvs\datavizproj\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3092, in plot
    ax = gca()
  File "C:\Users\Director UYE\.virtualenvs\datavizproj\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 828, in gca
    ax =  gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Director UYE\.virtualenvs\datavizproj\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 462, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "C:\Users\Director UYE\.virtualenvs\datavizproj\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 435, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Director UYE\.virtualenvs\datavizproj\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 81, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "C:\Users\Director UYE\.virtualenvs\datavizproj\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 89, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "c:\python27\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1814, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    c:/python27/lib/tcl8.5 {C:/Users/Director UYE/.virtualenvs/datavizproj/lib/tcl8.5} {C:/Users/Director UYE/.virtualenvs/lib/tcl8.5} {C:/Users/Director UYE/.virtualenvs/datavizproj/library} {C:/Users/Director UYE/.virtualenvs/library} {C:/Users/Director UYE/.virtualenvs/tcl8.5.15/library} {C:/Users/Director UYE/tcl8.5.15/library}



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment variable TCL_LIBRARY and TK_LIBRARY to point to the right directories and it should work.

Normally those are derived from the location of the arguments passed to the Tcl initialization routines, which is typically the dll or exe.

See http://wiki.tcl.tk/1629